# Python: statsmodels - what does .predict(X) actually predict?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm a bit confused as to what the line `model.predict(X)` actually predicts. I can't find anything on it with a Google search.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Step 1) Load data into dataframe 
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

# Step 2) Separate dependent and independent variables 

X = df['independent_variable']
y = df["dependent_variable"]

# Step 3) using OLS -fit a linear regression
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X) # make predictions
predictions
```

I'm not sure what `predictions` is showing? Is it predicting the next *x* amount of rows or something? Aren't I just passing in my independent variables?

Answer (score 1):

You are fitting an OLS model from your data, which is most likely interpreted as an array. The `predict` method will returns an array of fitted values given the trained model.

In other words, from `statsmodels` [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict):

> Return linear predicted values from a design matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the `sk-learn`. After `model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()`, you will have a model, then `predictions = model.predict(X)` is not predict **next** x amount of rows, it will predict from your `X`, the training dataset. The model using ordinary least squares will be a function of "x" and the output should be:

$$ \hat{y}=f(x) $$

If you want to predict the new `X`, you need to split `X` into `training` and `testing` dataset.

Comment: I'm missing something fundamental here. I get that you split your dataset 70/30: 70 to train, 30 to test, and then you select the best model. But what's the point of `predictions = model.predict(X)`? Can I pass in some random 'X' value and it will return a prediction, or is it giving me a separate set of X values to use for training (that are very close to the original X value)?

Comment: After your training, you pass in the `X` into the model for retrospective analysis. For example, you want to compare whether the model is underfitting or overfitting, you can use the training data output an error, and compare with the testing error. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing it wrong

The predict method is use to predict next values

After separating dependent and I dependent values

You can split the data in two part train and test

From sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,0.2)

This will make X_train ur 80% of total data with only independent variable

And you can put your y_test in predict method to check how well the model is performing

Comment: This is what I thought. The predict function surely should be taking  a target/y/independent variable?

Comment: No the predict method will take you independent variable as input and will try to give you your dependent variable as output

Comment: In simple after training your model with known dependent data you start passing only independent data in your model via predict method to get the dependent variable for which is unknown for that set of dependent variable